# Factorization of an analytic function in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let $f$ be analytic in $\Omega$. Assume $P\in\mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_n]$ is a polynomial whose irreducible factors are all of multiplicity one.

If $f$ vanishes on the zero set $Z(P)$ of $P$, how to justify that $f/P$ is analytic in $\Omega$ ?

(asked on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164508), but didn't get a convincing answer)

Comment: By restricting $f/P$ on complex lines and applying the 1-dimensional removable singularity theorem.

Comment: @Alexandre On second thought, something is not clear to me: the fact that  is square-free doesn't seem to imply that its restriction to a complex line is also square-free (think of $(_1−1)(_2−1)$ on the line $_1=_2$).

Comment: This occurs only for few lines. But you have an answer now, so I do not elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a copy of [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4654372/312406) from math.SE*

I think you could argue stalk wise. Take a point $x \in \Omega$. By general theory, the ring $\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n, x}$ of convergent power series at $x$ is a UFD. Since $P$ is square-free, and $f$ vanishes at $\{P =0\}$, $P$ is a factor of $f$ in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n,x}$ by the analytic Nullstellensatz. So there is a quotient $\overline{g_x} = f/P$ in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n,x}$. This is represented by an actual holomorphic function $g_x \in \mathcal O(U_x)$ in some neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$, and $g_x \cdot P = f$ holds on all of $U_x$. By the identity theorem, the $g_x$ glue to a holomorphic function $g$ on $\Omega$.